# Getting a value's key instead of getting a keys value?

Tags: java

How would I be able to get a specific key from its value. Instead of putting in the key and getting the value how would I be able to input a value and get a key?

Comment: Are you using a HashMap?

Comment: There may be multiple keys for the same value; which would you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with a simple `Map` (at least not in an efficient manner), because a key can have multiple values and the values have not been stored in a way that makes them quick to retrieve. Using just a regular `Map`, you would need to iterate over all the entries to find the corresponding keys for a value. However, you can create your own data structure that includes two maps (one from A to B, and the second from B to A) to create a bidirectional map with a 1:1 mapping, where you can lookup the A from B or B from A in O(1) time (I'm not using "key" and "value", because in a bidirectional map, both types are both). Check out [BiMap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap) ([HashBiMap source code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava-gwt/src-super/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.java)) from Guava for an example of this.